# When is the Hessian matrix of a convex function invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

> Let $F: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. Let
>   $\nabla^2 F(x)$ be the Hessian matrix.
>
> Are there specific conditions on $F$ (or $\nabla F$) that guarantees $\nabla^2 F(x)$
>   to be invertible on the domain of $F$ (e.g. all of $\mathbb{R}^N$)?

*Context: Newton's method requires inverse of $\nabla^2 F(x)$. Under what condition on $F$ do we have guarantee that $\nabla^2 F(x)$ can be inverted?*

Comment: F is strictly convex guarantees invertabilty of the Hessian

Comment: There are standard modifications of Newton's method to avoid problems with invertibility, for example, considering $\nabla^2f+\epsilon I$ at the points where the Hessian is ill-conditioned.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan That isn't true even in $1$-dimension. Consider $x^4$ for example. Positive-definiteness of the Hessian guarantees strict-convexity, not the other way around.

Comment: My bad. @EuYu, you're correct

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Is it true that if a function is convex, but not strictly convex, then its hessian will not be invertible on the domain of said function?

Comment: A sufficient condition for the Hessian to be positive definite (and hence invertible) is *strong convexity*, which is of course stronger than *strict convexity*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mlc noted, *strong convexity* of $F$ is a sufficient condition for the invertibility of its Hessian. Strong convexity means that there exists $c>0$ such that the function $F(x)-c\|x\|^2$ is convex. Under this assumption, all eigenvalues of the Hessian are $\ge 2c$, so they are nonzero.

Strong convexity is not necessary; e.g., $F(x)=\sqrt{\|x\|^2+1}$ fails it but nonetheless has invertible Hessian. But a necessary and sufficient condition would be tautological: the Hessian invertible when it's invertible.